# Python Pandas - Sampling: putting a limit on number of items on a Random selection

Tags: python, pandas, sampling

Say that I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
id_1 id_2
aa    123 
bb    123 
cc    234
dd    123
ee    678
FF    456
gg   123
```

How do I do sampling with the condition that we can only have up to 3 (or any other number) of identical items in **id_2** column? We don't necessarily need to have 3 or 2 items identical items for this column (as it is a random sample it has to be a random selection), but if it were to repeat it can be a max X times (defined by a threshold)

Say n=5 and threshold of 3

```
id_1 id_2
aa    123  
dd    123
ee    678
FF    456
gg    123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()

def get_sample(df, thresh):
    df1 = df.sample(n=5)
    while df1.id_2.value_counts().max() > thresh:
        print(df1.id_2.value_counts().max())
        df1 = df.sample(n=5)
    return df1

df1 = get_sample(df, 3)

print(df1)

    id_1    id_2
3   dd  123
4   ee  678
5   FF  456
6   gg  123
1   bb  123
```